# Matlab Facebook Information Gender Regognition

Tags: matlab, classification

Our teacher asked us to use any classifier to guess if a facebook user is male or female based on the information it has (Music, Books, Movies, Sports, People).

I divided Music, Books and Movies into genres and Sports to YES/NO and People (if he liked a page of a male or female) to Woman/Man.

For example `Music(1,1)=Hip Hop`, `Music(2,1)=Pop`.

In the second column, I put my guess if the user is male or female.

For example, I guessed `if Movie=Romantic then gender=woman` etc.

> [image: Changed Genres Matrix]

Then I made a matrix named `MuMoBSP` (Music, Movies, Books, Sports, People) and I entered my guesses and put 1 for male and 2 for female.

I found a C++ like way to make it work but I need to use classifiers. 
Can you help me?

My code is:

```
MuMoBSP=[1 1;2 1;3 2;4 2;5 2;6 2;7 1;8 1;9 1;10 1;11 1;12 2;13 2;14 2;15 2;16 2;17 1;18 1;19 1;20 1;21 1;22 1;23 1;24 2;25 2;26 2;27 2;28 1;29 2;30 1;31 2]


    filename='Facebook.csv'
    Data=dlmread(filename)

    %Music Based Gender%
    for k=1:6
        if (Data(1,1)==MuMoBSP(k,1))
            Gender(1,1)=MuMoBSP(k,2);
        end
    end

    %Movies Based Gender%
    for k=7:16
        if (Data(1,2)==MuMoBSP(k,1))
            Gender(1,2)=MuMoBSP(k,2);
        end
    end

    %Books Based Gender%
    for k=17:27
        if (Data(1,3)==MuMoBSP(k,1))
            Gender(1,3)=MuMoBSP(k,2);
        end
    end

    %Sports Based Gender%
    for k=28:29
        if (Data(1,4)==MuMoBSP(k,1))
            Gender(1,4)=MuMoBSP(k,2);
        end
    end

    %People Based Gender%
    for k=30:31
        if (Data(1,5)==MuMoBSP(k,1))
            Gender(1,5)=MuMoBSP(k,2);
        end
    end

    %Print if Man/Woman%
    if (sum(Gender)== 9)
        sprintf('woman');
    end
    if (sum(Gender)== 8)
        sprintf('woman');
    end
    if (sum(Gender)== 7)
        sprintf('man');
    end
    if (sum(Gender)== 6)
        sprintf('man');
    end
    if (sum(Gender)== 5)
        sprintf('man');
    end
    if (sum(Gender)== 10)
        sprintf('woman');
    end
```

`Facebook.csv` file is given below. Its 1st column is Music, the 2nd is Movies, the 3rd is Books, the 4rd is Sports and 5th is People.

```
2;7;17;28;30
1;8;17;28;30
2;10;23;28;30
2;11;22;28;30
1;7;21;28;30
2;9;18;28;30
1;7;19;28;30
3;12;24;29;31
4;14;27;29;31
4;16;27;29;31
6;13;25;29;31
6;14;26;29;31
5;16;27;29;31
5;12;26;29;31
```

> **UPDATE**
>   I changed the MuMoBSP and the data sheet(see at the top) like **hbaderts** suggested.

```
MuMoBSP =

     1     1
     2     1
     3     2
     4     2
     5     2
     6     2
     7     1
     8     1
     9     1
    10     1
    11     1
    12     2
    13     2
    14     2
    15     2
    16     2
    17     1
    18     1
    19     1
    20     1
    21     1
    22     1
    23     1
    24     2
    25     2
    26     2
    27     2
    28     1
    29     2
    30     1
    31     2
```

I tried to use the k-means function but I think I made some mistakes.

```
[idx,C] = kmeans(Data,2);
figure;
plot(Data(idx==1,1),Data(idx==1,2),'r.','MarkerSize',20)
hold on
plot(Data(idx==2,1),Data(idx==2,2),'b.','MarkerSize',20)
plot(C(:,1),C(:,2),'kx',...
     'MarkerSize',15,'LineWidth',3)
legend('Cluster 1','Cluster 2','Centroids',...
       'Location','NW')
title 'Cluster Assignments and Centroids'
hold off
silhouette(Data,idx)
```

Left Plot before silhouette
[image: Plot]

Why they are so far from the centroid?? How can I fix that?

Comment: Ok sorry now I found out how to do it

Comment: What is the problem that you're facing?

Comment: I have to use a classifier, for example knn, and don't know how... I think my logic is good but I haven't been taught anything about matlab!! Our teacher just said google it. I'm trying 2 months now and searched all the examples matlab has about knn and neural networks(fisheriris,arrythmia)

Answer (score 1):

### Theory

You are probably looking for *k*-means clustering. The idea is quite simple: we estimate a "prototype" male and female. If a data point (person) is closer to the average, prototype male, then it will also be a male. If the data point is closer to the average female, it will be a female. We do this using the following algorithm:

1. Choose *k* (in your case: 2) random initial centroid points.

Our two centroid points are our "prototypes" of a male and a female: an average female is specified by the centroid of the "female" cluster, and an average male is the centroid of the "male" cluster.

2. For each data point, we calculate the nearest centroid. If a data point is nearer to centroid 1, we assign e.g. the label "Male". If it is nearer to centroid 2, we assign the label "Female".

So far, this assignment is completely random - now we have to iteratively fit our clusters to the data we have.

3. For both clusters, we calculate the new mean value over all data points, i.e. the mean music genre, the mean movie genre and so on for our "Male" and "Female" clusters.

This new mean value is an approximation of the real underlying cluster means. So we repeat step 2, to assign the data points to the corrected clusters. Some data points which were previously "female" will now be assigned to "male", and vice-versa. Of course, some will stay the same.

As our clusters have changed, the mean values we calculated in step 3 have changed too, so we repeat step 3, and find our new cluster centroids. So we will also have to repeat step 2 again, and step 3 again, and so on. We repeat step 2 and 3, until our assignments don't change anymore, which means we have found a solution.

### Implementation in MATLAB

In Matlab, there is a [`kmeans`](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html) function, which makes this as simple as calling

```
idx = kmeans(Data, 2);
```

Of course, Matlab doesn't know about "male" or "female", so there is only cluster 1 and cluster 2, and it will be your job to judge which one is male, and which is female. I assume, the one who likes Sci-Fi movies and books, watches sports and follows women's profiles will be the man ;-)

### But wait...

Let's look at the music preference: in your code, you say the following:

```
1: Hip Hop     Male
2: Pop         Female
3: Jazz        Female
4: Metal       Male
5: Blues       Female
6: Rock        Female
```

if those 6 preferences are equally likely, an average man will have a "music value" of `(1+4)/2 = 2.5` and a female will have an average "music value" of `(2+3+5+6)/4 = 4`. So somebody who likes Pop music will be more likely to be a male, even though we don't want that!

Why does that happen? - For *k*-means clustering, we want inputs where a low value corresponds to cluster-1 and a high value corresponds to cluster-2 (or the other way around, that doesn't matter). The important thing is, that we need inputs which allow us to calculate meaningful "average persons".

If you can say, that Hip Hop is "a bit manly" and Metal is "very manly" music, while Rock is "a bit feminine", Blues is "more feminine", Jazz is "even more feminine" and Pop is "very feminine", you could change the labels to

```
1: Metal
2: Hip Hop
3: Rock
4: Blues
5: Jazz
6: Pop
```

then, somebody with a very high value listens to "feminine" music, while somebody with a low value listens to "manly" music. An average man will have a value of `1.5`, and an average woman will have a value of `4.5`.

If that is not the case (as it is probably in your case), you can for example create a bunch of new input variables:

```
x_1: Person likes Hip-Hop
x_2: Person likes Pop
...
```

where each variable is either `0` (false) or `1` (true). Instead of having 5 input variables, you will have e.g. 31 input variables, which are either `0` or `1`. This comes with the advantage, that you can use continuous values too: somebody who likes two pop bands and 3 metal bands can get a `0.4` for Pop and `0.6` for Metal.

Comment: That was really helpfull!! I'll try rigth now to do it :D